# В чем разница element.href и element.getAttribute("href")

Tags: javascript

В чем разница `element.href` и `element.getAttribute("href")`?
Еще видел как некоторые используют `getAttribute`, чтобы получить например data атрибут.

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button");


console.log(1, button.getAttribute("data-test1"), button.getAttribute("data-tupac"));

console.log(2, button.dataset.test1, button.dataset.tupac);
```

```html
<button data-test1="test 1 ..." data-tupac="Shakur">
```

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/dom-attributes-and-properties

Comment: Отлично, это дало ясность насчет ```href```, но не дало насчет ```data-*``` атрибутов. Написано, что для них лучше использовать ```dataset```, значит, те кто используют для этого ```getAttribute``` делают это не совсем правильно?

Comment: Тут получается такая же история. dataset - это обращение к свойству, а getAttribute к атрибуту элемента.

Comment: Возможно так по привычке пишут мастодонты из времён когда dataset ещё был не везде (читай IE10)